# Ошибка при запуске эмулятора Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Целый день пытаюсь победить.

**Сборка  заканчивается так:**
1>------ Сборка начата: проект: App17, Конфигурация: Debug Any CPU ------
1>App17 -> C:\Users\rupar\source\repos\App17\App17\App17\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\App17.dll
2>------ Сборка начата: проект: App17.Android, Конфигурация: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  App17.Android -> C:\Users\rupar\source\repos\App17\App17\App17.Android\bin\Debug\App17.Android.dll
2>  не удается разрешить конфликт между "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" и "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Произвольный выбор "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
========== Сборка: успешно: 2, с ошибками: 0, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========

**При  запуске  Эмулятора  получаю** 
1>Ожидание завершения проверок среды выполненияЗапуск проверок среды выполнения

Запускается эмулятор Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo...
H:\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -no-accel -avd Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo -prop monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo
Невозможно запустить эмулятор Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo.
Проверки среды выполнения завершены
Сборка была отменена.

**В журнале вот такая фигня**
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidSupportMismatchProvider|Warning|0|Failed to load package metadata from xamarin.android.support.annotations.nuspec to detect API level mismatch for reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.dll.
System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
   в Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidSupportMismatchProvider.DetectMismatch(String projectGuid, String templateGuid, String frameworkVersion, String referencePath) в E:\A_work\21\s\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Telemetry\AndroidSupportMismatchProvider.cs:строка 135

Comment: Поставьте Memu например, с родными плеерами вечно какие то непонятные траблы. И самое главное, когда он запуститься комфортно работать вы уже не сможете. Из рекомендаций подключать девайс шнурком или через вай-фай для отладки.

Comment: в него надо сборки  будет устанавливать или можно как то налету  настроить ?

Comment: Там это не сложно и руками, а автоматом можно через adb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставьте Memu например, с родными плеерами вечно какие то непонятные траблы. И самое главное, когда он запуститься комфортно работать вы уже не сможете. Из рекомендаций подключать девайс шнурком или через вай-фай для отладки.